# 'wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)' following Ruby and Rails upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I built a Rails app with Ruby 2.4.0 and Rails 5.1.2 and it was working fine.

I then upgraded Ruby to 2.5.5 and Rails to 5.2.3 (because Heroku demanded an upgrade) and when I click on a particular link I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):

app/helpers/permissions_helper.rb:21:in `block in <module:PermissionsHelper>'
app/helpers/permissions_helper.rb:60:in `instance_eval'
app/helpers/permissions_helper.rb:60:in `block in permissions'
app/helpers/permissions_helper.rb:60:in `select'
app/helpers/permissions_helper.rb:60:in `permissions'
app/controllers/models_controller.rb:66:in `validate_user'
```

permissions_helper.rb is as follows (lines 21 and 60 are marked with a comment):

```rb
    module PermissionsHelper

      PERMISSIONS = {
        User => [
          {
            requirement: ->{current_user.is_admin},
            actions: [:create, :read, :update, :destroy, :index, :update_all],
            rows: :all,
            cols: [:email, :username, :full_name]
          }
        ],
        ServiceGroup => [
          {
            requirement: ->{current_user.is_admin},  #line 21
            actions: [:create, :read, :update, :destroy, :index, :update_all],
            rows: :all_not_deleted,
            cols: [:service_group, :description]
          }
        ],
        ServiceType => [
          {
            requirement: ->{current_user.is_admin},
            actions: [:create, :read, :update, :destroy, :index, :update_all],
            rows: :all_not_deleted,
            cols: [:service_group_id, :service_type, :description]
          }
        ],
        Service => [
          {
            requirement: ->{current_user.is_admin},
            actions: [:create, :read, :update, :destroy, :index, :update_all],
            rows: :all_not_deleted,
            cols: [:service_type_id, :duration, :price, :format, :is_active]
          }
        ]
      }

      def action_type(action=action_name.to_sym)
        {
          show: :read,
          edit: :update
        }[action] || action
      end

      # Returns an array of permitted subtables {rows: ?, cols: [...]} for current request
      def permissions(model,action)
        return [] if !PERMISSIONS[model]
        @permissions ||= {}; @permissions[model] ||= {};
        action = action_type(action)
        return @permissions[model][action] if @permissions[model][action]
        mc = self
        @permissions[model][action] = PERMISSIONS[model].
          select {|h| mc.instance_eval(&h[:requirement]) && (h[:actions].include? action)}.  #line 60
          map {|h| {rows: h[:rows], cols: h[:cols]}}
      end

      # Returns all permitted rows for given model, action, e.g., User.where(:all_not_deleted)
      def permitted_rows(model,action)
        sets = permissions(model,action).map{|h| h[:rows]}.uniq
        sets.inject(model.send(sets.shift)) do |acc,set|
          acc.or(model.send(set))
        end
      end

      def fields(obj, action)
        if obj.is_a? ActiveRecord::Relation
          (relation = obj; model = relation.klass)
        else
          (model = obj; relation = nil)
        end
        @fields ||= {}; @fields[obj] ||= {}
        @fields[obj][action] ||= permissions(model, action).inject({}) do |acc, perm|
          new_fields = perm[:cols] - (acc[:cols] || [])
          new_rows = [perm[:rows]] - (acc[:rows] || [])
          if new_fields
            if new_rows.empty? || perm[:rows] == :all_not_deleted || relation.nil? ||
            relation.send(perm[:rows]).count > 0
              acc[:fields] = (acc[:fields] || []) + new_fields
              acc[:rows] = (acc[:rows] || []) + new_rows
            end
          end
          acc
        end [:fields]
      end
    end
```

The relevant code snippet from the ModelsController is as follows:

```rb
    def validate_user
      @models = (params[:models] || [params[:model]]).map {|m| m.camelize.constantize}
      puts "permissions for #{@models[0]}:#{action_name} = #{permissions(@models[0], action_type)}". #line 66
      @models.each do |model|
        puts permissions(model, action_type)
        break (redirect_to root_url) unless permissions(model, action_type).any?
      end
    end
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: I'm not sure _why_ you're getting that error, but if I had to guess I'd say it's from the ruby upgrade. I can't find anything in the changelog that seems like it would cause that though. If you're looking or a quick fix instead of an explanation, you could try replacing `instance_eval` with `tap`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mc.instance_eval` (at line 60) passes `self` to a block as an argument. Since you pass your lambda `->{current_user.is_admin}` (line 21) as a block then this function will receive 1 argument. But you didn't specify any arguments for this lambda, hence the error: `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0))`

Please, read about the differences between `Proc` and `Lambda` in ruby ([this article](http://awaxman11.github.io/blog/2013/08/05/what-is-the-difference-between-a-block/) for example)

Comment: Any idea why that would work before the upgrade and not after?

Comment: I didn't find any changes in ruby releases from 2.4.0 to 2.5.5 which could cause that and lambdas with this behavior existed long before 2.4.0. So I believe some code was changed after all along with ruby/RoR upgrade if it worked previously

Comment: definitely no change to any of the code shown.  That's why I'm so stumped as to why it's failing now.

Comment: Try reverting an update back to check why it worked previously but from what I see this code should fail with ruby 2.4.0. and rails 5.1.2 as well

Comment: Changing from -> to Proc.new worked, so your answer correctly explains why it's failing now. Just strange that it worked before.